# C++14 Functional logical_not on functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a logical expression, let's say `!a & b`.
However, instead of evaluating this expression, I would like to build a functional tree and defer the evaluation to later.
The values of `a` and `b` are computed using a function `value` so we have:

```
auto value_of_a = std::bind(value, _1); //I need an additional argument
auto value_of_b = std::bind(value, _1);
```

I would like to use `logical_not` and `logical_and` instead of using my own lambdas. However, they call a direct operator on the argument (for instance `!arg` for `logical_not`).
Therefore I cannot use something like:

```
auto v = std::bind(logical_not, value_of_a); //And we still need the first argument 
                                             //to call value_of_a
```

Can I bind the result (like some sort of Future) instead of the function?

I am trying to use as much already defined functions as possible for the sake of readability.
I am using C++14 but those are defined in C++11.

I am aware that using lambdas may be the easiest way, but I am trying to leverage as much as I can what already exists. However, I will fall back to them if the solution is not really better.

Thanks, hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Probably you meant `c++14` tag, not `c++11`

Comment: C++17 will have [`not_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn), which you might want to have a look at.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I really meant C++11 because all is defined in C++11 and is not limited to 14. I should had both though.

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes, but it's not there yet except in like experimental right?

Comment: "I am trying to use as much already defined functions as possible for the sake of readability." Out of curiosity, do you truly find the code you wrote clearer than a lambda?

Comment: What is `value` in `std::bind(value, _1);` ?

Comment: @AmiTavory I hope it will be when it will work.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The function to compute the value of `a` and `b`. I have updated the text, thanks.

Comment: @EmmanuelHadoux OK, but just to make sure, will your final result be equivalent to `auto not_a_or_b = [](bool a, bool b){return !a || b;};`?

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes, precisely. However, this evaluator is built inside a parser. I cannot know in advance what will be the expression.

Comment: `std::bind(std::logical_and<>{}, std::bind(std::logical_not<>{}, value_of_a), std::bind(value_of_b, std::placeholders::_2))`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It seems to work, thanks! I did not have this `{}` in my code and I am not sure why I need it. 
Moreover, does this mean that the parameter passed to this final bind is forwarded until a bind uses a placeholder?
Btw, how can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: @EmmanuelHadoux it's just a fancy way to initialize object of a type specified before `{}` :)

Comment: Some of the techniques discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates could potentially be applicable here (though you want to build a single calculation rather than a vectorized-type calculation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::bind(std::logical_and<>{}, 
              std::bind(std::logical_not<>{}, value_of_a),
              std::bind(value_of_b, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Provided that `value_of_a` is a bind expression, the above code is equivalent to:

```
( not value_of_a(#1) ) and ( value_of_b(#2) )
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cbb9a0f14d1d63f)

Comment: A beautiful example of why `std::bind` sucks.  +1